# Timeout Exception while retrieving from Redis Cache at the same place always

Tags: redis, stackexchange.redis, azure-redis-cache

We are receiving following timeout exception while retrieving data from Redis cache.

'Timeout performing GET inst: 2, mgr: Inactive, err: never, queue: 3, qu: 0, qs: 3, qc: 0, wr: 0, wq: 0, in: 18955,

IOCP: (Busy=4,Free=996,Min=2,Max=1000), WORKER: (Busy=0,Free=1023,Min=2,Max=1023),

Please note: Every timeout exception has different above values. queue is sometimes 2,1,3 and qs also varies with the queue value.
Also, IN: values keeps changing like 18955,  65536, 36829 etc.
Even IOCP changes like
IOCP: (Busy=6,Free=994,Min=2,Max=1000), WORKER: (Busy=0,Free=1023,Min=2,Max=1023).

Please note:

There are many similar questions in stack overflow and tried all of them. But, no luck.

We recently updated nuget package to the latest stable version (v1.2.1) of StackExchange.Redis library,

This exception seems to be occuring at the same place everytime even though there are various places where we are using redis cache. This has been found with the help of stack trace.

Also, we never faced this issue earlier like we are using the same solution from last 3 years and never encountered this issue. This exception has been occurring from last 3 months frequently atleast 3-4 times daily.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are experiencing threadpool throttling (from the Busy and Min numbers in your error message). You will need to increase the MIN values for IOCP and Worker pool threads.

https://gist.github.com/JonCole/e65411214030f0d823cb#file-threadpool-md has more information.